# NSDateFormatter returns nil since upgrade to ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, nsdateformatter

I have the following NSDateFormatter:-

```
self.dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
[self.dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

My string comes from a webmethod outputting a json String and is as follows:-

"2014-04-09T23:00:00Z"

My code to get the date is:-

```
estimate.date = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:jsonDate];
```

This was working fine for ios7 and the early builds of ios8. However I was not working on this project for some months and when I came to fix some reworks I installed the latest xcode (6.4) and the latest ios (8.4.1) and now the above code returns nil.

I have googled the hell out of this and everything says this should work.

Comment: I should add that this works fine in the simulator (ipad2) set to the exact same locale/language as my physical iPad.

Comment: Ok, I now know when it fails and when it works, but not what to do to fix the problem.
It works when the iPad is set to 24hr time format in setting but does not when set to 12hr. The simulator does not have this setting and is always set to 24hr.

Comment: Just for checking that: Did you try `[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]`?

Comment: The problem may be because you are setting a date format with a 24 hr format. Try other formats like: EEE, MMM d, ''yy (eg : Wed, July 10, '96 ) if you don't need AM/PM. (Just a guess from a newbie)

Comment: @Amin, tried that and did not work. It seems the only way to get this to work is to force the locale to US. What this has to do with 12/24 hr is beyond me.

Comment: There has been a change with locals and abbr in the past. Setting the locale could help. But a) with `-timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:` this shouldn't matter and b) IIRC it has been with iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

The only way around this is to set the locale to en_GB which forces the NSDateFormatter to use 24hours. It seems it ignores HH or hh and uses whatever the current locale is set to unless you override it!

```
[self.dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]];
```